# Angular component that takes HTML code as input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am creating an angular component that displays a highlighted HTML code and the result of it's execution. The displayed HTML code lives inside a pre html element, as for the preview of the result, it's hard-coded :

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-html">

&lt;button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger&lt;/button> <br> &lt;p> Hello World! &lt;/p>

</pre>
```

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<p> Hello Wolrd </p>
```

The result of using this component is as
[following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRE85.png)

Now what I want to do is to pass this HTML code as an input to this component. I tried to pass the code as a string using the following string :

```
&lt;button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Danger&lt;/button> <br> &lt;p> Hello World! &lt;/p>
```

The input what displayed as a string and was not executed displayed as an HTML code : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QGuA.png)

How can i use this input string to 1. display it as html code and 2. execute this code to preview the result ? Otherwise, what's the type that i should use for the input ?

Thanks for you're help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution for this is to create a custom pipe that bypass security trust html:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'sanitizeHtml'})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
  }
  transform(v:string):SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

Declare it in your module and use it where you want to display the HTML string :

```
<div [innerHTML]=" yourHTMLstring | sanitizeHtml "> </div>
```